# Appending dictionary values to array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, exc-bad-access

I have a dictionary of type 
`[String: Object]`, where `MyObject` is an array of `AnotherObject`. I need to have it sorted as I need to fill an UITableView with `Keys.count`number of sections and `Object.count` number of rows in each section. I put all the keys in an array, but when I try to append the values into another array I get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)`.

This is the code I'm using

```
var dictionary = [String: MyObject]()
var sortedKeys: [String]?
var sortedValues = [MyObject]()



func sortItems() {

        self.sortedKeys = self.dictionary.keys.sorted(by: >)

        let sortedDict = self.dictionary.sorted(by: {$0.key > $1.key})
        for (_, value) in sortedDict {
            print(value)
            self.sortedValues.append(value)
        }

    }
```

In the for loop, when I don't try to append the values to the array, it prints all the sorted values, the problem comes when I want to have them in an Array.

**Edit**

The dictionary is like this:

```
struct Object: Decodable {
    let elements: [AnotherObject]
}

struct AnotherObject: Decodable {
    let time, Id, Status: Int?
    let date, startTime, endTime: String?
}

dictionary: [String: Object]
```

So the keys are numbers (representing days) and every day has an Object with (at least) one anotherObject. 
I get the JSON from the API.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only sort the keys and then use that array to select from the dictionary and append your `sortedValues` array. I made the `sortedKeys` into a local variable

```
func sortItems() {
    let sortedKeys = self.dictionary.keys.sorted(by: >)

    for key in sortedKeys {
        if let obj = dictionary[key] {
            self.sortedValues.append(obj)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this will make a difference in regard to the crash but another way is to let the function return an array

```
func sortItems() -> [Object] {
    let sortedKeys = self.dictionary.keys.sorted(by: >)
    var result: [Object]()

    for key in sortedKeys {
        if let obj = dictionary[key] {
            result.append(obj)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

and then call it

```
self.sortedValues = sortItems()
```

Comment: I still get the ```Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8) ```

Comment: @ManuelLagunaMatias I can only assume this is because of something that happens elsewhere in your code. What other part of your code modifies the array? You say that MyObject is an array of AnotherObject, what does that mean?

Comment: I edited my comment... I don't know what can be happening, but the array is only being used in this method at the moment...

Comment: When is the decoding happening and is it asynchronous? I am wondering if the sort might happen while items are being added to the dictionary?

Comment: in ```viewWillAppear ```I make the api call, and right after inside the completion handler I call ```sortItems ```. As I said, if I print the values there's no problem. Problem comes when appending to array

Comment: @ManuelLagunaMatias I've made an update to my answer, not sure it will solve the crash but it might be worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `sortedKeys` at all and the result of sorting a dictionary is an **array** of tuples so the dictionary enumeration syntax `for (key, value) in` is wrong

Probably you want this

```
func sortItems() {

    let sortedKeys = self.dictionary.keys.sorted(by: >)

    for key in sortedKeys {
        let value = self.dictionary[key]!
        print(value)
        self.sortedValues.append(value)
    }
}
```

Force unwrapping the value is 100% safe as the key clearly exists.

Comment: I still get the ```Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8) ```

Comment: That's rather impossible as there are no optionals involved.

Comment: so we still don't know where the problem is but it's happening.